# Which one to use:Dataset or Datatable or Datareader

Tags: datatable, dataset, datareader

I have read articles on dataset, datatable and datareader, but still I am in confuse when to use what? Can anyone help me with examples to understand which one is proper in which context?

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: judging by your stats, the problem is not mine...

Answer (score 2):

A DataTable is an object used to store column and row data for a single table.

```
    Dim dt As New Data.DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("ColumnA", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("ColumnB", GetType(Int32))
    dt.Rows.Add("TestData1", 1)
    dt.Rows.Add("TestData2", 2)

    For Each dr As Data.DataRow In dt.Rows
        Response.Write(String.Format("{0}, {1}", dr.Item(0), dr.Item(0)))
    Next
```

A Datareader is an object used to read one row at a time from a database.

```
    Using oConn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand
        Dim oRead = oCmd.ExecuteReader
        While oRead.Read
            Response.Write(oRead.Item(0).ToString)
        End While
    End Using
```

A Dataset is a collection of DataTables.  With a Dataset you can also store relationships and constraints between parent tables and child tables.  You can essentially create an entire relational database in memory with a Dataset.  Datasets can be either created with code or created using the dataset editor in Visual Studio.  If you make it using Visual Studio (XSD file) the dataset becomes "typed", so you can refer to columns in compiled code by name instead of by index or literal.

```
    Dim ds As New dsMain
    Dim drParent = ds.ParentTable.AddParentTableRow("1")
    Dim drChild = ds.ChildTable.AddChildTableRow(drParent, "Somedata")

    Response.Write(drChild.ChildData & drChild.ParentTableRow.ParentId.ToString)
```

And the code for dsMain.XSD...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="dsMain" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/dsMain.xsd" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/dsMain.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/dsMain.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo source="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
      <DataSource DefaultConnectionIndex="0" FunctionsComponentName="QueriesTableAdapter" Modifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public" SchemaSerializationMode="IncludeSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
        <Connections />
        <Tables />
        <Sources />
      </DataSource>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="dsMain" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msprop:Generator_UserDSName="dsMain" msprop:Generator_DataSetName="dsMain">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="ParentTable" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="ParentTableDataTable" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tableParentTable" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="ParentTable" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="ParentTableRowDeleting" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="ParentTable" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="ParentTableRowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="ParentTableRowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="ParentTableRowDeleted" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="ParentTableRowChangeEvent" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="ParentTableRowChanged" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="ParentTableRow">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ParentId" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnParentId" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="ParentId" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="ParentIdColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="ParentId" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="ChildTable" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="ChildTableDataTable" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tableChildTable" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="ChildTable" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="ChildTableRowDeleting" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="ChildTable" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="ChildTableRowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="ChildTableRowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="ChildTableRowDeleted" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="ChildTableRowChangeEvent" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="ChildTableRowChanged" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="ChildTableRow">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ParentId" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnParentId" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="ParentId" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="ParentIdColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="ParentId" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ChildData" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnChildData" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="ChildData" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="ChildDataColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="ChildData" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="Constraint1" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//mstns:ParentTable" />
      <xs:field xpath="mstns:ParentId" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="ChildTable_Constraint1" msdata:ConstraintName="Constraint1" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//mstns:ChildTable" />
      <xs:field xpath="mstns:ParentId" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:keyref name="FK_ParentTable_ChildTable" refer="Constraint1" msprop:rel_Generator_UserChildTable="ChildTable" msprop:rel_Generator_ChildPropName="GetChildTableRows" msprop:rel_Generator_ParentPropName="ParentTableRow" msprop:rel_Generator_UserRelationName="FK_ParentTable_ChildTable" msprop:rel_Generator_RelationVarName="relationFK_ParentTable_ChildTable" msprop:rel_Generator_UserParentTable="ParentTable">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//mstns:ChildTable" />
      <xs:field xpath="mstns:ParentId" />
    </xs:keyref>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Hope this helps.